# Django - combining two models serializer into one JSON response

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have two models List and Card. I'm trying to combine these two and make a single JSON response

My List JSON response

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "List of things to do"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "one more"
    }
]
```

My Card JSON response

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "title": "My first scrum card",
        "description": "list things todo here",
        "story_points": null,
        "business_value": null,
        "list": 1
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "title": "File my taxes",
        "description": "fill it before 1st of nov",
        "story_points": null,
        "business_value": null,
        "list": 1
    },
]
```

My `serializers.py` file

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import List, Card

class CardSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Card
        fields = '__all__'

class ListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    cards = CardSerializer(read_only=True, many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = List
        fields ='__all__'
```

My `api.py` file

```
from rest_framework.viewsets import ModelViewSet
from .models import List, Card
from .serializers import ListSerializer, CardSerializer

class ListViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    queryset = List.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ListSerializer

class CardViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Card.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CardSerializer
```

My `models.py`

```
from django.db import models

class  List(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50) 

    def __str__(self):
        return "List : {}".format(self.name)

class Card(models.Model): # to create card table
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True) 
    list = models.ForeignKey(List, related_name = "card" 
    ,on_delete=models.PROTECT) # creating a foriegn key for storing list
    story_points = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank = True)
    business_value = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank = True)
    def __str__(self):
        return "Card : {}".format(self.title)
```

How can I achieve something like below in My List JSON response ?

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "cards":[
        {
            "id": 1,
            "title": "My first scrum card",
            "description": "list things todo here",
            "story_points": null,
            "business_value": null,
            "list": 1
        }],
        "name": "List of things to do"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "cards":[
        {
            "id": 2,
            "title": "File my taxes",
            "description": "fill it before 1st of nov",
            "story_points": null,
            "business_value": null,
            "list": 1
        }],
        "name": "one more"
    },
]
```

I have tried to do it but I was unable to implement it. So I posted it here.

### Heading

Many thanks.

Comment: Can you please also post your models?

Comment: @slider  is have added models

Answer (score 4):

You can also use SerializerMethodeField https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield.

```
class ListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    cards = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
       model = List
       fields = '__all__'

   def get_cards(self, obj):
       data = CardSerializer(obj.card.all(), many=True).data
       return data
```

Answer (score 3):

change the list `related_name` to `cards` and `ListViewSet` will do what you want

```
class Card(models.Model): # to create card table
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True) 
    list = models.ForeignKey(List, related_name = "cards"
    ,on_delete=models.PROTECT)
...
```