# Combining two serializer into one

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have a ListApiView where i list the data on a website and on the same page i could select the records and export to xl and pdf file here right now i am using same serializer called **ListingSerializer** for exporting the data to file and listing it, for listing the data and exporting the fields are same except for exporting i have two additional fields to be exported but right now i need two serializers one for listing **ListingSerializer** and other for exporting **ExportSerializer** without repeating the fields.

```
class ListingSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
    
        model = Mymodel
        fields = '__all__'



class ExportSerializer(serializer.ModelSerializer):
    date_records_received = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Mymodel
        fields = '__all__'


Class Mylist(ListAPIView):
    def get_queryset():
        return queryset
    
    def get_serializer():
        serializer = ListingSerializer(self.get_queryset(), many=True, context={'request': self.request})
        return serializer
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django - combining two models serializer into one JSON response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52933229/django-combining-two-models-serializer-into-one-json-response)

Answer (score 0):

You can inherit form another serializer. In your example:

```
class ListingSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
    
        model = Mymodel
        fields = '__all__'

class ExportSerializer(ListingSerializer):
    date_records_received = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
```